# How to print out the number of records given a condition

Tags: sql

I'm creating a SQL database for movies and I want to print out the number of movies that are Sci-Fi in the database.

I have ran this command, but I'm getting an error. 
Can anyone please points out to what is wrong in the command?

SELECT COUNT Genre FROM Movies WHERE Genre='Sci-Fi'

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: You should never store comma delimited values in a column. Read up on database normalization.

Comment: You marked an answer correct without even telling us what database you are using -1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`count` is a function, so you need to call it with an argument list in `()`. `count`, specifically, can get a special argument `*`, which means it will just count all the rows (that pass the filtering):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Movies WHERE Genre = 'Sci-Fi'
-- Here ----^
```

Additionally, since you `genre` column doesn't contain single values (a decision you may want to revisit), using the `=` operator like this will miss any movie that has multiple genres. Using `like` should do the trick:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Movies WHERE Genre LIKE '%Sci-Fi%'
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(Title) FROM Movies WHERE Genre like '%Sci-Fi%'
```

Comment: You answer is partial, you will miss records such as MoveiID=8

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Use below query

```
select count(*) from movies where Genre like "%Sci-Fi%"
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Movies WHERE Genre like '%Sci-Fi%'

Answer (score -2):

Try this one: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Movies WHERE Genre like 'Sci-Fi'`